# How much more effective at digging would an efficient late preindustrial power be compared to basic human labour?

Tags: science-based, technology, technological-development, infrastructure, pre-industrial

Following on from my earlier question here:
[Can a water transport canal be excavated by water power?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/190182/can-a-water-transport-canal-be-excavated-by-water-power?noredirect=1#comment588848_190182)

I have abandoned the self channeling as too difficult. So manual digging will be required. I need to get a handle on how big the canal might reasonably be. This will obviously depend (among other things) on the time and manpower available, so to simplify I will talk about cubic metres moved per man day.

Assume the same sand/loam/clay surface but add a solid rock foundation a few metres down (at a depth that is most convenient to construction). Take manual labor using basic picks, shovels and wheel barrows as an initial starting point for cubic metres dug per man day calculation.

The question is how much more efficient than this basic set up can they make their operation if they use a wider range of mechanical and animal based equipment and manage the work intelligently? All pre industrial devices are in scope, levers, pulleys, cranes, wheeled carts, horses, other animals and anything else that you can think of. What level of multiplier should I add to the basic mandrolic method?

There are no steam engines or internal combustion engines, but this society is very advanced in other respects. For example they are familiar with all manner of hydraulic calculations such as the manning equation for channel flow estimation.

Related:
[How long would it take to dig a 10 km canal with Bronze Age technology?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/166552/how-long-would-it-take-to-dig-a-10-km-canal-with-bronze-age-technology)

Comment: (a) Do we have explosives? But more to the point... (b) What's your question? How much more *efficiently* (aka, how much more quickly) can the canal be dug? As in, "humanity did X historically, but using hindsight, could we improve on that?" This is something of a weird question. Strainest thou at a gnat?

Comment: Just look at real world canals, a lot of canals were build before the industrial era. China and Britain being two poster children for it. As it is this question needs a lot of work. Consider just asking how fast can a canal be built preindustrial. The Bridgewater Canal would be a great example.

Comment: Its true there will be a lot of calculation (which I am happy to carry out) that’s why I tried to simplify the issue by avoiding the canal calculation. I’m interested in the technological advantage in digging of the late preindustrial period technology over very primitive digging methods – what multiplier to apply? x2? X5?

Comment: The 240 km (150 miles) [Canal du Midi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canal_du_Midi) was built in 14 years (1667 to 1681) over mountains and valleys, entirely by hand. And it wasn't even some sort of national effort of the Kingdom of France; it was an ordinary engineering project, one of many.

Comment: If you're really building a world, why does reality trump realism?

Either way, why not ask Google how long this, that or the other interesting canal actually took to build? These days, some even have their own TV doccoes!

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin I believe that keeping to reality will in the end produce a more satisfying and believable story. If I were to ignore the details the whole thing would very quickly degenerate into inconsistency and magic would be required to put it right. I have been doing a lot of research but some things are not that easy to discover even with googles help. This website has been extremely useful in picking holes in my thinking about such things.

Comment: @Slarty Why not try it? You might find you're a better writer than you thought.

If you think reality is more important than realism - outside textbooks - I suggest you read more! 

Picking holes in people's thinking is very important and even that doesn't alter the simple fact that far-and-away most readers are more than happy to suspend their disbelief, have their hands held and be led wherever the author takes them.

If you were about to research canal digging, which three projects would first spring to mind?

Comment: @AlexP That is an excellent source thank you. Perfect in terms of timeframe and a highly relevant on subject.

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin Reality v realism is an interesting point. I suppose in one sense what I am doing is very definitely realism and not reality. I’m sure that a group of trained engineers would drive a horse and carriage through the whole thing. Perhaps it takes a lot to suspend my disbelief. That said the idea of “letting go” does appeal in some ways. It would be much easier just to draw a line on the map and say they build a canal here, it was hard but they used magic. But then anything goes.

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin I have researched many projects. Suez and the pharaohs canal. Very useful in terms of Earth moving although in part by mechanization. The Roman project to drain the Fucine lake an reduce it by 15,000 acres.  The Panama Canal is not as good because of the disease problem and all of the locks. I have just discovered the Canal du Midi which is a fantastic resource – thanks to AlexP today particularly impressive in that is shows the scale of achievement in the 1600 which is the right period.

Comment: The Canal di Midi incorporated locks, something I do not think this project needs to worry about. I do not see any particular mechanical devices. I do not think even sluce gates would be useful, but perhaps a reservoir or two along the route to be able to build up a good head of water to increase water pressure in the lowerr sections (dry period for dredging, wet period for flooding.

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second Agreed locks aren't needed on this stretch of canal so that should make it easier to build. It's navigable but it's primary purpose would be the transportation large quantities of water. One thing I was a little worried about though -  at the source end there needs to be higher ground perhaps 100-200 metres higher in the last dozen miles or so. A natural hill / mountain barrier with a gap in it that is dammed. Then some impressive very high volume spillways perhaps a mile or two of them. Built in stages -  as difficult an engineering task as the canal itself maybe?

Comment: Something definitely for you to consider. It depends on how vested you are in the 'dug' part. Given the engineering works of the early Egyptians in building pyramids, the following is certainly do-able. You would have greater water pressure and greater flow if you built a decreasing sequence of 'patios' and sluce gates from the top of your reservoir. It does not get you the 'parabolic' shape traditional in the slope of engineered waterways, but it does get you an increasing 'head' pressure.

Comment: Think of a garden fountain that flows down through successive ponds and water falls. The only pump needed is the one to get the water up to the highest level.. We have had concrete from the time of the Romans. Very conceivable that your engineers also had it. The Egyptians moved lots of dirt to make gentle ramps up the sides of the pyramids, then removed the earth when construction was finished.

Comment: Moving large quantities of earth is just brute labor, nothing particularly challenging engineering wise, as long as you have enough manpower.

Comment: @Slarty Why be so negative about aims or means… the content of your World and your building methods?

It's always easier to draw a line and “build a canal…” by magic. Why would using your research, or making it up, be worse? 

Who knew what researching Suez and “the pharaohs canal”, the Fucine lake and the Panama Canal and discovering the Canal du Midi left unsaid about “late preindustrial power” and “basic human labour”?

What was “preindustrial power” but “basic human labour”? What was “the self channeling” and how was it “too difficult”?

Why not just write it realistically?

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin What was preindustrial power but human labor? Is exactly the point of the question I am asking here. I suggest its human labor magnified by animal labor and simple machines like cranes and windmills. Not massive, but significant. The self channeling referred to my previous question here:
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/190182/can-a-water-transport-canal-be-excavated-by-water-power?noredirect=1#comment588848_190182
The difficulty with it is the amount of sediment that would have to be moved given the location inland. I might come back to it later.

Comment: @Slarty Sorry and it reads as though "What was preindustrial power but human labor?" is exactly the point you're failing to address here".

Of course that's human labor magnified by animal labor and simple machines like cranes and windmills. Clearly huge - what you meant by "massive."

How would anyone realise self channeling referred to you previous question? Did you not know that link said nowt about "self channeling"?

Why would other work-styles not need to move sediment?

Why not drop what you might come back to later, until… uh… later?

Answer (score 6):

The longest canal in the world is also one of the oldest. The  [Jing–Hang Grand Canal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Canal_(China)) in China.

> The oldest parts of the canal date back to the 5th century BC, but the
> various sections were first connected during the Sui dynasty (581–618
> AD). Dynasties in 1271–1633 significantly restored and rebuilt the
> canal and altered its route to supply their capital.
>
> The total length of the Grand Canal is 1,776 km (1,104 mi).

This canal was built in part through a mountain range, with significant construction challenges, without augmented power machines. So certainly building your 400 km. canal on relatively flat lands in soil very amenable to digging (with very few engineering challenges) by a non-powered society is well within reasonable conjecture.

And I know from personal experience, having worked my way through University by working in a quarry, that a reasonably fit individual in a safety-conscious highly unionized environment can unassisted manually move six to eight cubic yards of material from an enclosed conveyor belt basement in an eight hour shift, using only a shovel and wheelbarrow, without an unreasonably excessive expenditure of effort. All breaks included. Troglyte labour could easily do it in half the time.

Comment: Thanks for that! I was trying to establish what advantage the late preindustrial tech would give for instance heavy lifting cranes

Comment: I can absolutely assure you that digging a trench 5 to 10 meters deep in very forgiving soil and moving the material a very short distance out of the way would not be significantly benefited by cranes and such, providing you have the manpower.  Cranes are only useful for heights and really heavy objects (boulders). The classical wheelbarrow and wagon would suffice. The only advantage powerd machines have (and basically they are just powered wheelbarrows, shovels, and wagons) is in manpower.

Comment: Instead of a crew of 20, a crew of two or three. If this were mining, in a confined space, the manpower reduction would be significant. How many workers can you cram in a mine? But in this case, you can spread as many workers as you want over the 400 km. length without them restricting other workers.

Comment: Consider the Western Front in The Great War was 700 km. long, and was essentially one long continuous trench, dug essentially by hand, upwards of four to six  meters deep and three to four meters wide, and it was manned by one contiguous line of soldiers from one end to the other, completed in only a few months to a year at most.

Comment: @Slarty it gets even better. The romans could already build a 90km aquaduct with water flow incline of 0.3%, dropping 264m in height. Most of it is until the halfway point, dropping 0.15% the rest of the way. Although aqueducts are different from canals, they showed they could make incredibly flat roads as well. It is likely they can apply the same incline to a canal. So they can't just build it, they can be very precise as well.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond: It wasn't *one* long continuous trench. It was a *complex system of trenches*, some 20 km wide on the average. At any given point both the Anglo-French and the Germans had dozens of more or less parallel trenches. The commonly agreed estimate is that the total length of trenches on the western from was about 55,000 km (35,000 miles).

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second I was thinking that it would help in larger canals if the base were say 6m down spoil from multiple barrows could be dumped into a large container and craned up to the top. Horse and carts could also be used with larger teams filling a cart instead of toing and froing with barrows - especially as the width increased

Comment: The advantage of horse-and-cart over cranes is that you can load a horse-and-cart anywhere, the cart is very mobile, but the crane has limited range.Also. at the top, you still have to dump it in a cart, so why not start with one and save a step? Five meters is no obstacle for a good horse team.  Pushing a wheelbarrow up a ramp to dump it in the wagon, earthen ramps are cheap to build and easy to move. I dumped the barrow load into a pan, which when full was carted away by a fork lift, but could just as easily have been a wagon pulled by a horse.  And for many reasons, I suggest sloped.banks.

Comment: But note, all the material you dig out can just be left beside the channel, to make the banks higher.

Comment: Despots are usually pretty good at getting things done.

Comment: @Charles Bamford  There were no 'despots' in the Great War - only very misdirected politicians. No one was trying to oppress anyone else. All sides thought the disagreement would be cleared up in months, and everyone would be home for Christmas.

Comment: Let's do some calculations. Assume a strong man can move 10 cubic meters of material a day (easily doable) with a shovel and wheelbarrow loaded into a horse drawn cart. A slice of channel one meter thick  by 20 meters wide by 5 meters deep (a decent size channel to serve the purpose) would take this person ten days to dig. For 400,000 meters, it would take 400,000 workers ten days to dig. Or 40,000 workers 100 days to dig. Or about 13,000 workers a year to dig. Or 100 powerd excavators and dump trucks four weeks at most to dig (10 cubic meters per scoop).

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond, when you do your calculations on what a man can do, do you take a healthy well fed modern man or a slave/serf who is basically underfed and not motivated (other than by the whip.) And I would not start the canal by digging 20 meters wide, 5 meter is enough to make the basic canal which you can next widen (if wanted at all) by dredging, which seems to be the easier way to work.

Comment: @Willeke Strange, your perspective, because no one mentioned slaves or slave labor. I do not have the foggiest idea of where that came from. Given the very shallow slope of thi channel, a five meter wide channel would not have enough water pressure to move the water all the way through. In my back-of-envelope calculations, 20 m is the minimum width necessary to provide enough water flow to keep everything moving. Unless you had perfectly frictionless banks and bottom. Because of friction, water within one meter of the sides would be almost stagnant. Drop is 10 cm in 1 km.

Answer (score 4):

Our local canal, the [Noordzeekanaal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Sea_Canal) was dug and build in the 1800's, the work took about 10 years and only a small part of the 25 km was actually dug by hand.
About 6.5 km (4 mile) through sand dunes was dug by hand and it was where a brook went most of the way through the dunes so not much height to dig.
That bit took a lot of effort and about as long as the rest dig/build through a lake, by dredging with whatever methods were available at the time, before steam was actually used in this kind of work.

As you can see in the Wikipedia link (to the canal name above) they dug a lake out deeper, used the soil from the bottom to build dikes to either sides and reclaimed the land to the outside of those dikes to use for fields.

The ground in the area is either sand (dunes,) peat (the land outside the former lake and dunes) and sand or clay at the bottom of the lake.

Once the initial canal was build/dug enlarging was done by dredging and removing the dikes and building new ones.

What you can learn from this is the time it took (building by hand through the dunes) and how to enlarge when you have a basic narrow canal.

Here the builders were lucky enough not to need to build over hills (or build aquaducts to build over valleys.) If you need those you will have to add years to the results.

How many years your canal will take depends mostly on the number of people you can put to work and how much money is invested, using simple machines or animal power will help, how much depends on the tech and animals used as well as the money invested.
It will make more sense to dig such a canal if it connects a series of communities or enlarges a river/brook which is already there but not useful (enough) for shipping. (Rather than to build through an area where there is nothing.)

Comment: Yes, you hit the nail right on the head. The time it takes completely depends on the will to spend the wealth needed to build it, even if the only wealth expenditure is in manpower that thereby can not used for some other economic purpose. The trench on the Wester Front was built using readily available wealth - the manpower was already there, not going anywhere else. The only wealth expendeture was the cost of shovels.

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second What I was actually asking was how much improvement "mechanisation" like cranes and horses would provide compared to the basic man shovel and a wheel barrow. I get the impression that it would not be a lot, but on a large project such as this would, I suspect, have some effect. Obviously the time it takes depends on the size of the work force etc etc.

Comment: Horses, or some sort of beast of burden, would definitely make the project go a lot faster. Especially when the terrain is flat and unobstructed. A human can move 8 cubic meters of soil in a day. a horse pulling a wagon can move it in a fraction of an hour. So, say one horse equals 32 men, in moving the soil, but I have never seen a horse that can DIG better than a human. As far as I know, humans are the best means of digging until steam power and steam shovels came along (except maybe for hydroblasting). But even then, it took diesel to finally make a pronounced difference.

Comment: Plowing, however, is another thing. A beast of burden can plow in soil that a human could never do.